# Bootstrap 3 tables column width control

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap table as follows:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col1</th>
      <th>Col2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>  
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The two column are equally spaced which is fine but if i drop an `<input>` element in to one of the columns this column stretches to take up about 3/4 of the overall table.

http://www.bootply.com/115049

My question is why does it do this and how can I control it?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is down to the way HTML tables work. By default, table cells will scale according to their contents - any size you give them is used as a guide. So, for instance:

```
td {
    width: 50%; 
    /* 
       If this cell is empty, it will take up half of 
       the table. But if the content needs to, it will 
       expand to take up more space. 
    */
}
```

You can work around this by setting `table-layout: fixed;` in your CSS:, e.g.

```
table.fixed {
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

This makes tables adhere more strictly to the dimensions you set in CSS, rather than what the content dictates. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout for more information.

Once this is done, you can apply the normal [Bootstrap grid classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) to control the width. Apply them to the cells (`td` or `th`) in the first row and they'll repeat all the way down.

Answer (score 4):

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th class="col-md-10">Col1</th>
  <th class="col-md-2">Col2</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>  
<tr>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: oldie but still relevant for bootstrap 3

Answer (score 0):

Why ? I don't know :)

How to control it ?
You can simply but a width parameter to your td, such as :

```
<td width=50%><input type="text"></td>
```

You can do it like this, or using your css file by saying all  from this class should take half of the table width.

```
td {
    width: 50%;
}
```